# Curvillinear Dataset.swap_dims or ncks --rgr infer coordinate variable specification option

Tags: python-xarray, nco

I have an xarray.Dataset of the following form:

```
Dimensions:            (projection: 1, south_north: 1230, time: 48, west_east: 1269)
Coordinates:
  * time               (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-02-05T06:00:00 ... 2017-02-17
    lon                (south_north, west_east) float32 ...
    lat                (south_north, west_east) float32 ...
  * west_east          (west_east) float32 -457.4113 -455.40988 ... 2079.0415
  * south_north        (south_north) float32 -1184.8442 -1182.8433 ... 1273.5972
Dimensions without coordinates: projection
Data variables:
    precip_bkt         (time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
    Lambert_Conformal  (projection) int32 ...
```

south_north and west_east are the coordinates from a Lambert Conformal Projection (for which have the details to fully specify). I did not create this file, but from what I understand, there should be a bijection between (lat,lon) and (west_east, south_north). Thus, one could presumably use something like Dataset.swap_dims to make lat and lon the dimensions and west_east and south_north the coordinates.

However, it [looks like](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.swap_dims.html) Dataset.swap_dims only supports a single variable version of this operation. At the moment, I get the following error:

```
ds.swap_dims({"west_east":"lon", "south_north":"lat"})

---------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-0a066deaef31> in <module>
----> 1 wrf_ds.swap_dims({"west_east":"lon", "south_north":"lat"})

~/miniconda3/envs/hv-gv-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in swap_dims(self, dims_dict, inplace)
   2150                 raise ValueError('replacement dimension %r is not a 1D '
   2151                                  'variable along the old dimension %r'
-> 2152                                  % (v, k))
   2153 
   2154         result_dims = set(dims_dict.get(dim, dim) for dim in self.dims)

ValueError: replacement dimension 'lon' is not a 1D variable along the old dimension 'west_east'
```

This makes sense. I have not told swap_dims all the information it would need, it should not work properly.

Is there currently a way to specify that I want to swamp two coordinates for two dimensions? The documentation does say "dict-like" rather than "dict", so perhaps there is some flexibility here. If this behaviour is not supported right now, is it a feasible feature?

To be clear, I want the following type of behaviour:

```
ds.swap_dims(["south_north","west_east"]~["lon","lat"]) # specify a relationship between dims and coords \
#' I am not sure what a real pythonic syntax for this would be

Dimensions:            (projection: 1, lat: 1230, time: 48, lon: 1269)
Coordinates:
  * time               (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-02-05T06:00:00 ... 2017-02-17
  * lon                (lon) float32 ...
  * lat                (lat) float32 ...
    west_east          (lat, lon) float32 -457.4113 -455.40988 ... 2079.0415
    south_north        (lat, lon) float32 -1184.8442 -1182.8433 ... 1273.5972
Dimensions without coordinates: projection
Data variables:
    precip_bkt         (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
    Lambert_Conformal  (projection) int32 ...
```

I need the dimensions to be 'lat' and 'lon' or 'latitude' and 'longitude' so nco (ncks --rgr infer --rgr scrip ...) can generate a grid description file for regridding.

If there is another tool (such as nco) which can solve this problem, I am also interested. Perhaps there could also be a way to tell nco's "--rgr infer" that I want to use a coordinate rather than a dimension. This would also solve the problem, and might be more straightforward.

My searches about "swapping dims" or "exchanging coordinates and dimensions" only bring up results of changing the order dimensions are listed in.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try, e.g.,

ncks --rgr infer#lat_nm=south_north#lon_nm=west_east#scrip=grd.nc in.nc foo.nc

as documented [here](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#rgr_tbl)?